# What is Unmanifest & what is Person? And what's the difference?

Tags: upanishads, katha-upanishad

Katha Upanishad Valli 3 says such.

**7**. Higher than the senses is the mind; 
Higher than the mind is the essence; Higher than the essence is the **immense self**; 
Higher than the immense is the **unmanifest**.

**8**. Higher than the unmanifest is the **person**, pervading all and without any marks. 
Knowing him, a man is freed, and attains immortality.

- Immense self is Jivatma(Pushtak).
- Person is Brahm or ultimate reality.
- Then what Unmanifest is?

And what is the difference (possibly subtle) between unmanifest & Person?

Comment: Doesn't sthula sharira means gross body? Material body? that is not Jivatman.

Comment: Okay. But it is Jeevatma. Right?

Comment: @Seeker If you have Sanskrit verses, you can quote them. It makes question more clear. :)

Comment: Don't have for now. Will update once I find.

Comment: `Immense self` means `Maha-tattva` means `Antah Karan` of `Samashti` not `Jivatma`.

Comment: So Atma is actually Maha-tattva?

Comment: @Seeker oh! I think there's a difference between Samkhya and Vedanta interpretation over this. Yes, you're right, it stands for Jivatma according to Vedanta (Brahma Sutra 1.4.1) and Avykta (Unmenifest) should be Maya/Prakriti/Karan-Sharir of God. Purush(Person) stands for Paramatma or Brahman.

Comment: In Vedanta interpretation Unmanifest is being said as Isvara. -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://www.swami-krishnananda.org/katha1/Commentary_on_Katha_Upanishad.pdf) On page 224, this is the translation

> इन्द्रियेभ्य: परं मनो मनस: सत्वमुत्तमम् | 
>   सत्त्वादधि महानात्मा महतोsव्यकतमुत्तमम् ||7||
>
> indriyebhyaḥ param mano manasaṣ sattvam uttamam,
>   sattvād adhi mahān ātmā, mahato’vyaktam uttamam. (7)
>
> Beyond the senses is the mind, higher than the mind is
>   the intellect, higher than the intellect is the great Atman,
>   higher than the mahat is avyaktam (the unmanifested).
>   (II.3.7)
>
> अव्यक्तात्तु पर: पुरुषो व्यापकोsलिङ्ग एव च | 
>   यं ज्ञात्वा मुच्यते जन्तुरमृतत्वं च गच्छति ||८||
>
> avyaktāt tu paraḥ puruso vyāpako’liṅga eva ca,
>   yaṁ jñātvā mucyate jantur amṛtatvaṁ ca gacchati. (8)
>
> Beyond the avyakta is Purusha, all-pervading and
>   devoid of linga (indicative sign). He who knows Him is
>   liberated and obtains Immortality. (II.3.8)

And on page 162, this is commentary.

> Why do you go to the senses as if they were everything?
>   “The mind is superior to, and controls the, senses. The
>   intelligence controls the mind; superior to the intellect is
>   the mahat-tattva beyond which is mulaprakriti, of which
>   hiranyagarbha is the manifestation. Beyond everything is
>   the purusha.” Why don’t you go to the Supreme Being?
>   Why to the senses which are the lowest manifestation? This
>   purusha is all-pervading, and nothing is greater than He.
>
> Unfortunately for us, we cannot define this purusha.
>   The mind and the senses can be defined; hiranyagarbha
>   and virat can be symbolically explained, but not the
>   purusha. We cannot define anything without reference to
>   its qualities and attributes, but He is devoid of these, and
>   He is therefore undefinable. “He is alinga—but if you have
>   the blessedness to realise Him by some means or other,
>   titiksha is attained.” The purusha without any mark cannot
>   be meditated upon. So different Upanishads give us
>   definitions and qualities of Him to be meditated on, like 
>   satyam, jnanam, anantam, vijnanam, tat tvam asi, etad vai
>   tat, etc. These are symbols; not definitions of God. There
>   are various symbols, including the idols in temples. Any
>   one will do, provided it is taken as the final one. By this, the
>   purusha can be realised.

It seems "senses" in your translation is Samkhya tattva of panchendriyas, "mind" is samkhya tattva of manas, "essense" in your translation is samkhya tattva of buddhi/intellect. "great atman" is sankhya tattva of mahat. "Unmanifest" is sankhya tattva of mulaprakriti and "person" is purusha tattva of samkhya.  http://www.hinduwebsite.com/24principles.asp

Edit: Vedanta interpretation of these verses can be more clearly seen [here](http://www.srimatham.com/uploads/5/5/4/9/5549439/katha_upanishad.pdf) on pages 37 to 39

> The order of gradual inversion from the external world is being discussed. We experience
>   the presence and power of the five sense-organs, we then reflect upon our perception of
>   their objects and the relevance that we give them. We then reflect upon the mind that
>   collates the data, we then progress to the contemplation of the intellect, to the process of
>   understanding the thinking process itself. Once we transcend this state of thinking about
>   thinking we can then perceive the Self as it is.
>   arthāḥ = the “things” of the senses that have no meaning in themselves but the meaning
>   that we give them.
>
> **Great Self** = Shankara means by it the great “Self of the universe” said to be the firstborn
>   of the Unmanifest. According to the RX. (X.121) in the beginning was the chaos of
>   waters, floating on which appeared Hiranya-garbha, the golden germ, the first born of
>   creation and the creator of all other human beings. **Hiranya-garbha is the Self of the
>   Universe. RV.X.129.2.**
>   **For Ramanuja the Great Self is the individual Self or the subject of all experience which
>   is indwelt by the Highest Self.**
>
> **The Unmanifest**. It is beyond mahat or the Self, it is prakṛti, the universal mother Nature
>   from out of which, by the influence of the light of purusa, all form and all content emerge
>   into manifestation.
>   Shankara suggests that the "Unmanifest” is the latent state of the whole universewhen
>   name and form are unmanifested. The state when all forces of cause and effect are in a
>   latent condition prior to manifestation. **It is the same as Māyā – Illusion and Avidya –
>   ignorance.** Puruṣa (That which fills, or the Supreme Person) is the subject, Prakṛti or
>   material nature is the object, both are co-ordinate principles at the stage of cosmic
>   creation, while their inter-action is essential for all manifestation, Puruṣa is considered to
>   be higher as he is the source of light and his unit appears nearer to the Ultimate One than
>   the multiplicity of Prakrti; strictly speaking, however, the Pure Self is beyond the
>   descriptions of unity, duality and multiplicity.
>   For Shankara, the “Unmanifest” here is not the Prakṛti or Primordial Nature of the
>   Sankhya System but the māyā-śakti which is responsible for the whole world including
>   the personal God. For Ramanuja, **Unmanifest denotes the Brahman in its causal phase,
>   when names and forms are not yet distinguished.** It is a real mode, prakāra or
>   development, a real transformation of Brahman through which the universe is evolved
>   and comes into being.
>
> The Puruṣa – The term Puruṣa goes back to the Puruṣa Sukta (R.V. X. 90) where it is
>   used in a distinctly personal way. The Ultimate Reality or Brahman contains all
>   possibilities of manifestation and non-manifestation of both subject and object, both the
>   light of unity and the darkness of multiplicity – **Puruṣa is the subjective side of that
>   Brahman.** We do not reach it, until the end of the cosmic day when the entire universe is
>   reabsorbed into Brahman. So from this point of view we can say that there is nothing
>   beyond the Puruṣa.

So as per Sankara, great-self/mahat is hiranya-garbha and unmanifest is maya and avidya.
As per Ramanuja, great-self/mahat is individual self, jivatman and unmanifest is Brahman in its casual phase.

Purusha is subjective side of Brahman.

Comment: Please, Do update with Vedantic interpretation as well.